# Remove characters in PHP using regular expressions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table column with a lot of rows.

Below is a sample of the data format:

```
TEST-DATA (ID:123)
```

How can I remove the part `(ID:123)`, using PHP regular expressions?

Please note that `(ID:123)` contains different numbers for each row in the table column.

```
TESTDATA2(ID:1)
DATAAGAIN(ID:78)
MOREDATA(ID:45)
...
```

Comment: are you saving the id data as a text in your database?

Comment: no. i dont need the ID and everything in the brackets. i just need the text that is outside the brackets.

Comment: eg for TEST-DATA(ID:123) i need to remain with TEST-DATA only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

> preg_replace — Perform a regular expression search and replace

Example:

```
echo preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/", "", $value);
```

Expression breakdown:

```
/  - Opening delimiter 
\( - Match an opening parenthesis 
[^\)]+ - Match one or more characters that are not a closing parenthesis 
\) - Match a closing parenthesis
/  - Closing delimiter
```

Replace `$value` with the variable for your column value.

Comment: I would also include `\s*` before the opening parenthesis.

Comment: you mean like this :  echo preg_replace("\s*/\([^\)]+\)/", "", $value);
?

Comment: thanks for the tip Aleck. The \s* means ignore spaces at the beginning, right?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$string = preg_replace( '/\(ID:[0-9]+\)/', '', $string );
```

Comment: I would also include `\s*` before the opening parenthesis.

Comment: Gentlemen, you are truly the best people on the planet!! 
It worked perfectly.